# Github Pages: Automatic Table of Contents on a page with jekyll-theme-minimal or some other them which can be switched to easily?

Tags: github, github-pages

I have blog which uses Github Pages & is forked from jekyllnow.

I use the jekyll-theme-minimal in my _config.yml (I think this may be inherited from jekyllnow, I don't remember).

On each page, I want an automatic Table of Contents (TOC) generated using all the `#, ##, ###` tags.

Is this possible with jekyll-theme-minimal or if not, then through some other theme which will can be easily moved to. I have a lot of existing pages & I don't want to change themes in a way which will require a lot of changes to make the existing pages work jut fine with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a Liquid Based TOC which is trivial to integrate - https://github.com/allejo/jekyll-toc

Comment: Good catch, well done. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

You could either use a plugin (but you need to adapt the build process), or add your ToC yourself within your [jekyll-now fork](https://github.com/barryclark/jekyll-now) (the default build is then enough).

### Use a plugin

Using [`jekyll-toc`](https://github.com/toshimaru/jekyll-toc) or any non-whitelisted plugin with a Jekyll site hosted on GitHub Pages requires a different approach because GitHub Pages only supports a limited set of plugins for security reasons. You will need to change the build process of your `jekyll-now` fork.

For that, you can use GitHub Actions to build your site and deploy the resulting `_site` directory to a `gh-pages` branch.

- Create a new file in your repository: `.github/workflows/jekyll_build.yml`.
- Add the following content to the `jekyll_build.yml` file:

  ```yaml
  name: Build and deploy Jekyll site to GitHub Pages

  on:
  push:
      branches:
      - master

  jobs:
  build:
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest

      steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Ruby
      uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
      with:
          ruby-version: 2.7

      - name: Build Jekyll site
      run: |
          gem install bundler
          bundle install
          bundle exec jekyll build

      - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
      uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v3
      with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          publish_dir: ./_site
  ```

Then you need to configure the Jekyll TOC Plugin

Add the [`jekyll-toc`](https://github.com/toshimaru/jekyll-toc) [gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/jekyll-toc/versions/0.17.1) to your `Gemfile`:

```rb
group :jekyll_plugins do
  gem "jekyll-toc"
end
```

And run `bundle install`.

Then update `_config.yml` to include the plugin:

```yaml
plugins:
  - jekyll-toc
```

Use the plugin in your layouts: For example, in `_layouts/post.html`, where you want the TOC to appear:

```
{{ content | toc }}
```

When you push your changes to the `master` branch, the GitHub Action will trigger. It will build your Jekyll site with the plugin and then deploy it to the `gh-pages` branch.
Make sure your GitHub Pages setting is set to serve from the `gh-pages` branch (see "[Configuring a publishing source for your GitHub Pages site](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site)").

Now, each time you push to `master`, the site will be built with the TOC plugin and deployed to the `gh-pages` branch.

### Add ToC manually

That approach does not depend on any plugin, and would not require a build change.
You can use a simple script to generate a TOC from your headers. Add this at the end of your post layout (`_layouts/post.html`):

```html
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var toc = "";
    var level = 0;

    document.getElementById("post-content").innerHTML =
        document.getElementById("post-content").innerHTML.replace(
            /<h([\d])>([^<]+)<\/h\1>/g,
            function (str, openLevel, titleText, closeLevel) {
                if (openLevel > level) {
                    toc += (new Array(openLevel - level + 1)).join("<ul>");
                } else if (openLevel < level) {
                    toc += (new Array(level - openLevel + 1)).join("</ul>");
                }
                level = parseInt(openLevel);

                var anchor = titleText.replace(/ /g, "_");
                toc += "<li><a href='#" + anchor + "'>" + titleText + "</a></li>";

                return "<h" + openLevel + "><a name='" + anchor + "'>" + titleText + "</a></h" + openLevel + ">";
            }
        );

    if (level) {
        toc += (new Array(level + 1)).join("</ul>");
    }

    document.getElementById("toc").innerHTML += toc;
});
</script>
```

Then prepare your content. Make sure your post's content is wrapped in a `div` with an `id` of "`post-content`":

```html
<div id="post-content">
    {{ content }}
</div>
```

Add a placeholder for the TOC: Wherever you want the TOC to appear, add an empty `div` with an id of "`toc`":

```html
<div id="toc">
    <strong>Contents:</strong>
</div>
```

Optionally, you can style the ToC: Include it in your main stylesheet or within a `<style>` tag in your head section.

```css
#toc ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
#toc li {
    margin: 5px 0;
}
#toc a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

That uses a combination of JavaScript and CSS to generate a TOC based on your headers (`#, ##, ###, ...`).   It does not require any Jekyll plugins, so it is fully compatible with Jekyll Now and will work on GitHub Pages without any additional setup.

---

> My [`_layouts\post.html`](https://github.com/barryclark/jekyll-now/blob/master/_layouts/post.html) already has `<div class="entry"> {{ content }} </div>`: what do I do with that?

If your `_layouts/post.html` file already has a `<div class="entry"> {{ content }} </div>`, then you can either directly insert the TOC code above that div or within it, depending on where you want the Table of Contents to appear.

#### Inserting TOC above the Content

```html
---
layout: default
---

<article class="post">
  <h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>

  <!-- Insert TOC here -->
  <div id="toc">
      {{ content | toc }}
  </div>

  <div class="entry">
    {{ content }}
  </div>

  <div class="date">
    Written on {{ page.date | date: "%B %e, %Y" }}
  </div>

  {% include disqus.html %}
</article>
```

#### Inserting TOC within the Content

```html
---
layout: default
---

<article class="post">
  <h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>

  <div class="entry">
    <!-- Insert TOC here -->
    <div id="toc">
        {{ content | toc }}
    </div>

    {{ content }}
  </div>

  <div class="date">
    Written on {{ page.date | date: "%B %e, %Y" }}
  </div>

  {% include disqus.html %}
</article>
```

Either way, this will include the TOC in your post, generated by the `jekyll-toc` plugin. As previously explained, you will still need to set up GitHub Actions to build the site if you are hosting it on GitHub Pages, because GitHub Pages does not support custom plugins by default.

Comment: My _layouts\post.html already has `  <div class="entry">
    {{ content }}
  </div>` https://github.com/barryclark/jekyll-now/blob/master/_layouts/post.html - what do I do with that?

Comment: Do not understand the  `<div id="post-content">
    {{ content }}
</div>` part. Does this mean I copy this exactly somewhere or do I put `<div id="post-content">` about the actual content in my actual content file & also close the div at the end?

Comment: I didn't copy the above but added it in my actual content file & I now have all the post content copied twice in the generated file. Once inside a <div> entry & once inside a <div> post-contents.

Comment: Also the last line of your answer is confusing - `Remember to include the jekyll-toc plugin in your Gemfile and _config.yml as previously described` - earlier you indicated that this method doesn't depen on any plugin?